# How can I convert modal dialog window to non-modal dialog window in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, loops, exec, show

I have a multiple `QDialog` windows. All windows are created with `exampleWindow->exec()`. This caused only one window is open at the time.

I have to convert these windows to `non-modal dialog window`

Here sample code example of my project. When the exec() is using the system is going into loop and wait for the user do something on the window.

```
int result = exampleWindow->exec();

if ( exampleWindow== QDialogButtonBox::Ok )
{
    exampleWindow->UpdateCalibrationData(&data);
    exampleWindow->UpdateFilterData(&filterData);
    SetCalibrationStatusToSuccess();
}
```

But I want to convert this one to like that:

```
exampleWindow->show();
// and I need to some loop here for the wait answer of dialog
```

Comment: `exampleWindow->show();` will open your dialog in non modal mode. If you loop after this call, you will probably block your GUI.

Comment: I know this is open non modal dialog. But in this case how can i wait for windows?

Comment: Connect `QDialog::accepted ()` signal to your slot. It will be called as soon as you close your dialog with "OK" button, i.e. accept it.

Comment: You don't want a loop. You want asynchronous style, where your code is automatically triggered when the dialog is accepted or rejected.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a non-modal dialog with

```
exampleWindow->show();
```

After the user closes the dialog, you can get the signal emitted by the dialog:

```
QObject::connect(&exampleWindow, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(doSomething());
```

and receive the dialog data in that slot function.

Answer (score 3):

I did'nt have enough reputation to be able to comment. But if with a `QDialog` you can just call `myDialog->show()` If you have your dialog as a member variable it can only have 1 open instance of its self. If you want to make something non modal there is a setting or a flag you can set on that dialog.

```
    QDialog::show();
    QDialog::setModal();
```

If you have a look at the documentation. Please could you make your question a little clearer? What is your actual problem? Or is it just preference how you want your `QDialog` to be shown. As the post above me shows you can check for signal and slots for if the Dialog has been closed/accepted.

Its better to use

`QObject::connect(obj, &Class::signal, obj, &Class::slot)` - this will give compiler errors if the signals and slots cant connect.

Than

`connect(obj, SIGNAL(), obj, SLOT())` - where as this will only give you a run time error. But will not crash or output a warning and will just continue.